# Self-intersection of a curve $C\subset \Bbb{P}^2$ after $3$ blow-ups

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory, blowup

Let $P_0,P_1,P_2\in\Bbb{P}^2$ points in general position,consider the lines $\ell_i:=\overline{P_jP_k}$ for $\{i,j,k\}=\{0,1,2\}$ and the blow-up $\pi:S\to\mathbb{P}^2$ at $P_0,P_1,P_2$.

[image]

I was told in that the strict transform $\widetilde{\ell}_i\subset S$ of $\ell_i$ is supposed to have self-intersection $-1$, and that we may then apply Castelnuovo's contraction theorem successively to each curve $\widetilde{\ell}_0,\widetilde{\ell}_1,\widetilde{\ell}_2$.

I can't see why it should be $-1$. Take for example $\ell_2=\overline{P_0P_1}$, which has self intersection $0$. Now, since $\ell_2$ passes through both $P_0,P_1$ with multiplicity $1$, then:

\begin{align*}
0&=\ell_2^2\\
&=(\pi^*\ell_2)^2\\
&=(\widetilde{\ell}_2+E_0+E_1)^2\\
&=\widetilde{\ell}_2^2+E_0^2+E_1^2+2\widetilde{\ell}_2E_0+2\widetilde{\ell}_2E_1+2E_0E_1\\
&=\widetilde{\ell}_2^2-1-1+2+2+0
\end{align*}

Therefore $\widetilde{\ell}_2^2=-2$. Analogously, I've found $\widetilde{\ell}_0^2=\widetilde{\ell}_1^2=-2$.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Related: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51193/geometric-motivation-for-negative-self-intersection) and [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2450021/self-intersection-number-of-the-proper-transform-of-the-line-at-infinity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lines in $\Bbb P^2$ have self-intersection $1$, not $0$. We can write $l_1^2=l_1.l_2$ for any other line $l_2$ via rational equivalence, and it's clear that two distinct lines in $\Bbb P^2$ intersect in a point.